# Power BI - Percent of two categories total

Tags: powerbi

Data structure:

```
[Branch],[Product],sum([Units]), % of Product/Branch
```

I can't figure out how to do the last column, which is the `%` of each product that makes up the total branch units.

I can get the `%` of each product within the total units, but not within just the branch units.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a little data example?

Comment: Makes more readable